# Grails reverse engineering shows invalid column when scaffolding

Tags: hibernate, grails

I see lot of posts related to Hibernate and reverse engineering. But I could not find anything related to this. Sorry if I am repeating already answered and closed, please post the URL if anyone is aware of it.

My issue is Grails shows invalid column when I use reverse engineering when I used scaffolding. Reverse engineering creates the domain class as per existing data base. So I don't want to change anything in Database or Automatically created domain class as part of reverse engineering. There must be some solution other than editing the domain class or DB column.

Error:

```
....Error 
|
2015-02-04 07:52:41,004 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Invalid column name 'category_id'.
Error |
2015-02-04 07:52:41,132 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SQLServerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /reverseEng/expense/index
Invalid column name 'category_id'.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Invalid column name 'category_id'.
    Line | Method
->>  197 | makeFromDatabaseError      in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1493 | getNextResult              in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement
|    390 | doExecutePreparedStatement in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement
|    340 | doExecute                  in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd
|   4575 | execute . . . . . . . . .  in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand
|   1400 | executeCommand             in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection
|    179 | executeCommand . . . . . . in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement
```

Code:

```
Used the plugin : compile ":db-reverse-engineer:0.5.1"
Changed the hibernate to   runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"  instead of 4
```

Domain class- Category

```
package com.reverseEng

class Category {

    BigDecimal intCatId
    String strCatName

    static hasMany = [expenses: Expense]

    static mapping = {
        id name: "intCatId", generator: "assigned"
        version false
    }
}
```

Domain class Expense

```
package com.reverseEng

class Expense {

    Double fltAmt
    Date dtDate
    Category category

    static belongsTo = [Category]

    static mapping = {
        id column: "intTranId", generator: "assigned"
        version false
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.reverseEng

class ExpenseController {

    /*def index() { }*/
    static scaffold=Expense
}
```

Category controller:

```
package com.reverseEng

class CategoryController {

   /* def index() { }*/
    static scaffold=Category
}
```

DB Structure: MSSQL

table Category:

```
intCatId numeric(19,0) Autoincrement Primary key
strCatName varchar
```

table Expense:

```
intTranId int Autoincrement primary key
fltAmt Float
dtDate date
intCatId Foreign key to the Category table.
```

Config.grrovy is updated with

```
grails.plugin.reveng.packageName = 'com.reverseEng'
grails.plugin.reveng.includeTables = ['category','expense']
```

Executed `grails db-reverse-engineer` then executed `run-app`.

Comment: ....Error 
|
2015-02-04 07:52:41,004 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Invalid column name 'category_id'.
Error |
2015-02-04 07:52:41,132 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SQLServerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /reverseEng/expense/index
Invalid column name 'category_id'.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Invalid column name 'category_id'.
    Line | Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never trust generated code. Assume that this plugin and anything else that generates code for you is at best a decent timesaver, but whether you type every character by hand or start with generated code and fix it, the net result must be working code that you understand and trust.

The core issue here is that you have a property named `category` in the `Expense` class but it has no mapping configuration, so it uses the default naming approach for converting class and property names to table and column names. Since it's a reference to another persistent class, its column name is derived by converting the camel-case property name (in this case there are no internal uppercase chars) to an underscore-delimited column name and adding `_id`, so it's `category_id`. But the column name is `intCatId`, so you need to add that to the `mapping` block.

There are a few other issues, and I would take advantage of the chance to have sensible variable names instead of using the redundantly prefixed VB-style naming used in the database. If your variable names describe what they do they rarely need prefixing or other hints.

For the `Category` class I'd change the name property and add a `column` mapping, and remove the explicit primary key property like in `Expense` and just specify its column name:

```
class Category {

    String name

    static hasMany = [expenses: Expense]

    static mapping = {
        id column: "intCatId", generator: "assigned"
        name column: 'strCatName'
        version false
    }
}
```

Add a mapping for `category` in `Expense` to specify `intCatId` instead of `category_id`, and like for `Category` I'd make the date and amount properties human-readable (and combine the explicit `category` field with the `belongsTo` map since both approaches have the same effect):

```
class Expense {

    Double amount
    Date date

    static belongsTo = [category: Category]

    static mapping = {
        id column: "intTranId", generator: "assigned"
        amount column: 'fltAmt'
        date column: 'dtDate'
        category column: 'intCatId'
        version false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This got worked for me. your suggestions leading to the concern that hibernate with existing databases will need manual effort to fix it even though it sets major parts. I am doing this as pilot project to show how much supportive to migrate existing applications...

Comment: vraiment.. bravo .. يعطيك العافية .. يعطيك الصحة